# get specific intent using events in Dialogflow Essentials

Tags: dialogflow-es

Trying to get specific intent using events in Dialogflow Essentials

below is the request

```
   {
    "queryInput": {
        "event": {
            "name": "start",
            "languageCode": "en"
        }
    }
}
```

response:

```
{
"responseId": "4f2e-8de0-e5ae7ef17a60-32d6a6f2",
"queryResult": {
    "action": "input.unknown",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true
}
```

Same working when using text. Would like to make it work using event as well

```
{
    "queryInput": {
        "text": {
            "text": "start",
            "languageCode": "en"
        }
    }
}
```

response:

```
{
    "responseId": "4e9b-b131-f5598b8d7f11-32d6a6f2",
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "start",
        "parameters": {},
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the intent has an event attached to it so you can detect intents based on events.

Intent configuration:

[image]

[image]

Request body:

```
{
  "queryInput": {
    "event": {
      "name": "test",
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  }
}
```

Response when used [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) endpoint:

```
{
  "responseId": "7330fd68-82d1-4fa5-b5a1-555a9d4f649b-32d6a6f2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "test",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "From API",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "From API"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/xxxxxx/agent/sessions/1234/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "no-input": 0,
          "no-match": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/xxxxxx/agent/intents/05356807-86f4-4a13-8079-6745b110a4d5",
      "displayName": "test intent"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```